# How to fmap the first element of a tuple in haskell

Tags: haskell, functor, applicative

I'm trying to write a function like

```
mapFst :: Maybe (a, String) -> Maybe ([a], String)
mapFst (a,s) = (:) <$> (a,s) <*> [other fun with same type as mapFst] (a,s)
```

Here, I'm trying to build a list based on the first element of a tuple, but I'm not sure how to proceed. I can do it for a non-tuple, but am not sure how to use `fst` within this construct (if I should be using that function in the first place).

This function will interface with another of the same type, but have slightly different ways of handling their input. I need to use fmap and ap because the tuple is inside a `Maybe` container

Comment: Your `otherFunWithSameTypeAsMapFst` --- does it have the same type as mapFst *now* (`Maybe (a, String) -> Maybe ([a], String)`), or the same type as mapFst had before you edited the question (`(a, String) -> ([a], String)`)?

Comment: They both have the `Maybe` container

Answer (score 8):

It's not clear from your question, but I think you want `first` from Control.Arrow.

```
first (*1000) (3, 4)
>>> (3000, 4)
```

---

Building on your edit and dbaupp's answer, maybe you want

```
mapFst (a,s) = case otherFunc (a,s) of
                    Nothing -> ([a], s)
                    Just (as:s') -> (a:as, s')
```

Comment: See my modified question and comment on the other answer

Answer (score 2):

```
mapFst (a,s) = let (as, s') = otherFunc (a,s) in (a:as, s)
```

(It's not clear how you want to handle the `String`s: you can change the `s` to `s'` or `s ++ s'` or whatever is needed.)

Comment: Sorry, my question was not stated clearly. I don't wish to simply make a list of a. I need to interface this function with another function of the same type that will trade off in the way they handle that first argument.

Comment: Your method would work if I were just interested in the tuple. I guess I should reveal the next step of my thinking, which is that the tuple is actually inside a `Maybe` container, so I have to use `fmap` and `ap`.